# Big O Notation Example Show that N^2 is not O(n)

Tags: big-o

Show that n^2 is not O(n)

```
f(n)=n^2
g(n) = n
c = 1
n_0=2

n^2 <= 1*n for all n_0 >= 2
4 <= 2 
4 is not less than or equal to 2. Therefore, n^2 is not O(n).
```

I need to show that NO c works with this, however, the c of 2, with n of 2 will work. How is n^2 not n?

Comment: What do you mean by `c`?

Comment: BIG O-->  f(n) <= c(g(n)) for all n >= n0 ... c is a contant

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's assume that *n²* is in *O(n)*.

Then there must be a *c* and a *n₀* such that for all *n ≥ n₀*, *n² ≤ c*n* (by the definition of O notation).

Let *k = max(c, n₀) + 1*. By the above property we have *k² ≤ c*k* (since *k > n₀*), from which it follows that *k ≤ c*.

However, *k > c* by construction. That's a contradiction.

Therefore our assumption is false and *n²* cannot be in *O(n)*.

Comment: Where does k come into play from this? Examples I have seen, there hasn't been a k. Trying to understand it a little more if you don't mind

Comment: @soldfor k is a local variable I defined for this proof.

Comment: What I don't get is n^2 can be O(n), right? Again, if c and n were 1, then it's correct. If c is big enough it would also work with lower ns.

Comment: @soldfor No, n^2 can't be O(n). You can't just look at a single (small) n; big-O is all about asymptotic behavior; i.e. it's a property that must hold for all values above a certain cut-off point called n₀. You can choose n₀ and c as big as you want, but if n is big enough, n^2 will exceed c*n. The n₀ threshold means you can ignore small values of n if you want, but you can never ignore big n.

Comment: Ok. When I was asking my professor on this, he mentioned that I have to prove that NO c and n will work. And it looks like the contradiction way works that way.